# TypeError: this.scale.setScreenSize is not a function

Tags: phaser

Game work with the old version 2.0.6. But they get this error after switching to 2.4.2

```
TypeError: this.scale.setScreenSize is not a function
```

any Idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 6):

I found this in the [changelog](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecated):

```
Deprecated [...] ScaleManager.setScreenSize (see updateLayout)
```

Try replacing your call to setScreenSize with updateLayout -- that worked for me.

Comment: Sure thing! I had the same problem, so I'm glad I could pass on a fix.